# Android Work Profile: android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED never fired

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-work-profile

I am working on an application that communicates with a backend over SMS (Actually Data SMS).

Outgoing and incoming SMS works perfectly in a regular setup, however one of our users have an Android [Work Profile](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949?hl=en) enabled and the app is installed within the work profile.

Now the app does not receive the DATA_SMS_RECEIVED intent. I have tried to find any documentation on this but have found none. Is there anything special I need to do in order to make DATA_SMS_RECEIVED work on a work profile?

Here is the relevant manifest declaration:

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcastreceiver.SmsReceived" android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
        <data android:port="1234" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And here is the relevant code from the BroadcastReceiver

```
public class SmsReceived extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String DATA_SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try{
            if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(DATA_SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)){
                //Code here is not executed when installed in work profile
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

Please note: this is an internal app and Androids new SMS restrictions does not apply.

Comment: I am having a similar issue on a phone with a work profiles. Google Pixel4. But the intent is ACL_CONNECTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED that is not fired, (bluetooth events). Let me know if you solve this one! @www.jensolsson.se